# Thread.Sleep for up to seven days in a Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm currently working on a Azure WebJob application that has a queue `newUsersQueue`. This queue is populated by a associated website, which adds new users to the queue when they create an acount, and the objective of the webjob is to send an email to users if they have had no activity during their first week of membership. Each object in the queue has data to identify the user, and a DateTime `RegisteredDate`.

I am assuming the queue will be ordered by date users join, so that oldest users end up first in the queue, because of FIFO(first in first out)

My current approach is then to grab the first item in the queue from the webjob, and simply `Thread.Sleep(DateTime.Now.Subtract(RegisteredDate.addDays(7)))`

Since resources are limited, I'm now worrying this might be expensive. Maybe there are other issues too that I haven't thought about(this thread might sleep for up to 7 days, waste of a thread?)?

Is there a better(more cost-effective) approach to achieve this? I've been considering using a timer or somesuch. what would the benefits of a timer/other approach be over sleeping?

Is there any risk of loosing a queue-message from sleeping for a week after popping it of the queue? ( is it loaded to memory and removed from queue? ) persistence is of course important too.

---

From what I've learned so far my decision essentially boils down to how Azure Webjobs handle queues. Will it startup new threads at will to handle queued messages, or will it stick to 1 thread, and have it take it's time with the existing queue?

In other words, will the above method start a new thread for each new user, or will stick to one thread and handle queued objects one at a time?

Comment: You should probably use a timer, that launches daily, and checks for users that meet `x` business requirements and then send appropriate emails.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to keep this in memory?  Why can't you just run the job once a day and check the `RegisteredDate` in the database where the users are stored?

Comment: @EBrown yes this is one of the main alternatives I have been considering. I'm not sure about the benefits though, my current solution executes only when needed, then sleeps, while this alternative executes daily, even if not needed...Care to elaborate a bit on the benefits of this alternative approach using timers? maybe it's possible to "peek" at the next queue-message without removing it from the queue, so that I might set up the timer to execute only when actually needed? (I'm new to WebJobs, sorry if this seems dumb)

Comment: @WyattEarp I COULD do that, but the userdatabase is rather huge,so it would be extremely resource-expensive to traverse it all each day. Plus such a huge operation on the database could come at the cost of users having to wait for it to finish, which could be literately minutes, which is unacceptable.

Comment: @AndersMartini As long as there is an index on the RegisteredDate, it should be fast enough, no?  You could just grab the users that were registered in the last 7 days and check for no activity.  I'm not too familiar with WebJobs and obviously don't know any of your architecture, so take it with a grain of salt...

Comment: Executing the program once a day to check users is going to be a hell of a lot less expensive than maintaining a thread for every new user for a week ..

Comment: would it maintain a new thread for each user though? in that case I have completely misunderstood how queues work. I thought it would only keep one thread per queue, and then process each element in that thread one at a time!

Comment: Well even if that were true, you are still telling the thread to sleep for every user it encounters, so it'd only deal with one user per week ..? Without the code it's hard to tell you what it will do.

Comment: Also, if you're storing this queue in memory, what happens if it crashes?  The users in the queue are going to be lost.  I really think the best solution is to retrieve the user information from the database.  I suspect that your time will be better spent if you work on getting an efficient schema/query.

Comment: @AndersMartini As Sippy said, the `Timer` is **much** cheaper than holding threads. And yes, each time it runs you would check your queue (or what have you, hopefully it's a database table) and see if there are any *things* it has to do.

Comment: I was going to say, my main concern would be any issues which cause the service to lose context. Memory issues, server faults, downtime, all that.

Comment: Also, if you are concerned about database performance you should use indexes, stored procedures, and proper optimization strategies. You should also benchmark it first, to see if there *really is* a performance impact. And if you use right-proper `WHERE` clauses, indexes, and SP's, you would have very few (if any) performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a scheduled WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduled).

Choose recurring, run it whenever you want, make sure that the logic you use to check for users in your criteria is efficient, that's probably the most expensive part assuming you have a lot of users. If not, this isn't expensive, really.

One way you could do this if you're worried about expensive queries is add new users to another table, check this table every day for users that have logged in, remove them from this table. If a user gets to 7 days, send an email, then remove or do whatever you want to do with them. Then, assuming you only had 300 new members a week, you'd only have to query 300 users, not 10k.

Comment: Will this be more resource-efficient than using a queue? I'm not really sure how queues are implemented in Azure so I have no idea. It seems odd that polling the database(with 10k+ users) would be faster/cheaper than having a queue set up?although I guess it would save me having a open Thread. I just don't know which is more expensive..is the cost of queued webjobs documented somewhere? I haven't been able to find that..

Comment: 10k users isn't an expensive query to do once a day. If you grow at a rate of 300 users per week, having 300 threads open consistently is expensive.

Comment: @AndersMartini Not only is that a tiny database (we have a database here at work with 5.3 million records that I have a programme that selects data from on-demand) but if you do most of the processing on the SQL server, it will be extremely cheap and efficient. You merely need to make sure indexes are properly built, and that you add what stored-procedures need added. With the right-proper database tuning, you would never know it was on a database.

Comment: This @EBrown guy gets it :P

Comment: well..convinced, I guess It'l be easier to implement as well =) thanks guys!

Comment: out of curiousity though, how Does these queues work? will they start up one thread per queued-message? seems like a rather odd thing to do...anyone knows for sure?

Comment: Though this question has been answered, one thing that bothers me with this queues based approach (and I am assuming you're using storage queues) is that a message can only live in a queue for a maximum of 7 days. So if you are checking the queue after 7 days, the message would expire automatically.